# axios doesn't store cookie but in response is setCookie=.... Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and withCredentials php - laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, credentials

i wanna get passport cookie in react.js
i fixed all of thing in .htaccess  and i can get the cookie with javascript

but it isn't store in browser storage

[image: cookie is here but didn't store]

this is my code in front with axios

.htaccess

```
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials  "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
```

react.js

```
axios.get("http://domin.com/JwtCookie", {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

        withCredentials: true,
    }).then(re => console.log(re)).catch()
```

i try it with another cookie but there is this problem too

thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

The [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers `Access-Control-Allow-...` are not **request** headers, they are **response** headers so you should set them on the **response**.

Also, you need to set the [`Samesite=None`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) attribute on the cookie. After that, your cross-domain cookie will be sent by the browser.

Comment: i set the 2 header   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true", in .htaccess ...

Comment: And the cookie attribute?

Comment: I tried it on different cookies =>  cross-site-cookie: samesite:"None"
value:"bar"

Comment: I think your problem is that [`Samesite=None`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) also requires `Secure` so you have to enable HTTPS